# Delphi XE3 Debugger doesn't work any more

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe3

The Delphi XE3 Debugger doesn't work as before. I have checked all needed option settings and then rebuilt the project. The lines I want to set breakpoints will be marked blue and I can check it (changes to red). But after pressing F9, all blue dots disappears and the breakpoint's red dot will turn into a red dot with a white X. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you're building a release-build. Change it to debug and rebuild.

Comment: No, Build configuration = Debug. After setting active, I rebuilt the whole project.

Comment: Sounds like this code is never executed, e.g. a function that is not called. Are you sure that the code is reached at all?

Comment: Yes! All executable lines are marked with blue dots after the build.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem as yours, you may try right-clicking the `.exe` file located at the "Project Manager" and then choose `Clean`.

Comment: What is Clean for? See this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723821/delphi-ide-project-cleancommand-what-does-it-do]

Comment: Don't just post the link @RookieDelphi. Add some information from the link,so in the future if the link is dead(specially link to other website),people will still view information here that you are referring to.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is long time ago, but did you try to rebuild your project (shift + F9)?
I often have these kind of problems (I'm currently using delphi 10.1 berlin, but the same with previous environments)